# Como aplicar Regex en el KeyUp?

Tags: javascript, ionic

necesito algo de ayuda con expresiones regulares y como aplicarla. estoy tratando de aplicar una funcion en donde necesito hacer que mi caja de texto aplique mi expresion regular ,esto es lo que tengo:

```
public ApplyRegex(event: any) {

const NUMBER_REGEXP = /^([A-Za-z0-9\\\ñ\\\Ñ ]{220})/;

let newValue = event.target.value;

let regExp = new RegExp(NUMBER_REGEXP);

if (!regExp.test(newValue)) {

event.target.value = newValue.slice(0, -1);

}

}

<ion-input (keypress)="ApplyExpreg()" [(ngModel)]="textCapture" type="text"></ion-input>
```

Acepta letras, numeros, y Ñ y acepta hasta 220 caracteres necesito q valide en el keyup pero Alparecer solo se cumple cuando el value es de 200 caracteres,

Ha si estoy haciendo esto con ionic3. Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Buenas, si en la expresión regular pones {220} estas diciendo que tiene que ser de tamaño 220, tendrías que poner un rango de {0,220} o lo que consideres necesario.

Comment: ah okey,  gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La expresión debería ser algo como `/^[a-z0-9ñÑ ]{0,220}$/i`

- De 0 a 220 es `{0,220}`
- `\\` hace que encuentre una coincidencia con `\` literal (`156/2` va a pasar)
- usando el flag `i` hacemos que sea insensible a mayúsculas minúsculas
- El `^` (principio) y `$` (fin) son necesarios en este caso, porque sino `.test()` te encuentra una coincidencia si hay una subcadena que coincida.
- Cuidado que acentos (`á` por ejemplo) no van a pasar.

Comment: vale, gracias por tu explicacion al final me funcionó de esta manera:

Comment: `public ApplyRegex(event: any) {
    const NUMBER_REGEXP = /^([A-Za-z0-9\\ñ\\Ñ]{1,4})/gm;
    let newValue = event.target.value;
    var result = newValue.match(NUMBER_REGEXP);
    console.log(result);
    event.target.value = result;
    if (!result) {
      event.target.value = newValue.slice(0, -1);
    }
  }`

Comment: puse {1,4} para hacer pruebas rapidamente.